# how to loop though sub folder to check if folder is empty inside batch script?

Tags: windows, batch

**What I want to do:**

1. write a batch script to do the following
2. loop though all dir starting with "01-"...
3. Check if "Pictures" folder is empty or not. skip rest folders
4. If "Pictures" folder is Empty, than print path of empty "Pictures" folders.

**Output Example:**

MainFolder/01-Folder3/Pictures is empty

**Structure of my folder:**

1. 1st lvl... Every thing inside my "MainFolder"
2. 2nd lvl... all folders start with a number ex: 01, 02, 03, etc...
3. 3rd lvl... There is folder called "Pictures"... in every 3rd lvl

**here is an example:**

```
    |>MainFolder 
    |--->01-Folder1
    |------->Pictures
    |----------->pic.png
    |----------->SubPicFolder
    |------->RandomFolder1
    |------->RandomFolder2
    |--->01-Folder2
    |------->Pictures
    |----------->SubPicFolder
    |------->RandomFolder1
    |--->01-Folder3
    |------->Pictures
    |------->RandomFolder1
    |--->02-Folder1
    |------->Pictures
    |------->RandomFolder1
    |------->RandomFolder1
```

**What I have tried?:**

```
@echo off
for /d /r %%A in ("Pictur*") do (
    dir /a /b "%%~fA" 2>nul | findstr "^" >nul || echo %%~fA
)
pause
```

**Problem with what I have tried:**

This code does print all empty "Pictures" folder but issue is that it checks all the folder.
I just want to check folder starting with "01-" and subfolder "Pictures". skip rest.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
for /f %%A in ('dir /a:d /b /s ^| find /i "01-" ^| find /i "pictur"') do (
echo checking %%A ...
dir /a /b "%%~fA" 2>nul | findstr "^" >nul || echo found empty: %%~fA
)
pause
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your answer to give an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because they don't teach the solution.